# What is AirWatch in Salesforce?Why&How to use it in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile

Iam newbie to AirWatch in salesforce. I would like to learn about AirWatch, how and why we need this in salesforce. What are all the supported AirWatch apps in salesforce.

I didn't get proper documentaion for this from google. Could you please any one help on this.

Thanks,

Comment: You may be better off Googling than posting this as a question here.

Comment: You need to provide more context here -- AirWatch is about managing devices/apps/.. for the Enterprise; Salesforce 1 would be an example of what is managed.